# ORDER BY 2 Field names with specific values

Tags: php, mysqli

Hi guys i need help with mysqli

I want to order by fiend with specific value, here is 1 field

```
$results = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `data` ORDER BY field(mu,'Legija Stranaca Elite','Legija Stranaca') ASC, level Desc");
```

how do apply a 2nd ORDER BY using the same

Comment: That seems like a valid query, so what's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to simply use another field() condition in the order by part of your statement e.g.

```
$results = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `data` ORDER BY field(mu,'Legija Stranaca Elite','Legija Stranaca') ASC, field(anotherfield,'Something Else','Another thing') ASC, level Desc");
```